# How to update panda based on condition when the value to be assigned is depending on another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
 a    b      e
 123  abc    yes
 123  lef    yes
 xa2  xyz    no
 405  mtc    yes
 xyzl pdl    no
 4n5  mtc    yes
```

How can i update column `a` where column `e == 'yes'` i am trying the below approach but it fails

```
df.loc[df['e'] == 'yes', 'a' ] = my_func(df['b'])
```

where the right hand side or the value needs to be assigned based on the return value from a function of column b

Comment: whats the error message?  and what the function do?

Comment: `df.loc[df['e'] == 'yes', 'a' ] = df['b'].apply(my_func)`

Answer (score 0):

You should go with the suggested design by cs95 in the comment as it does the trick in one liner.

However, if you want to take it in 2 separate lines (which I find more intuitive at least when you begin using pandas) you can:

**1. Find the indexes in question**

```
    my_indexes = df[df['e']=='yes'].index
```

**2. assign your value/function to those inexes with:**

```
    df.loc[my_indexes,'a']=my_func(df['b'])
```